# How to remove user input from Android Seekbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-widget, seekbar

when I use seekBar.setEnabled(false), it will grey out the seekbar. Is there any way to keep the original color and brightness of bar even after disabling it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using `ProgressBar` instead?

Comment: @CommonsWare I need the thumb as an indicator in my slider app...so thought of using seekbar instead of progressbar.

Comment: Isn't the color change of a `ProgressBar` a sufficient "indicator"?

Comment: Even without further context this sounds like it's not actually what you want to do. Platforms like Android have UI conventions for certain elements that appear so that users can glance quickly at the screen and understand how everything works. When users see an enabled SeekBar with a thumb, they expect that they can grab it and drag it around. Any other behavior will be perceived by the user as the app being broken, because you will have designed an app with a broken UI. :)

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry man...I didnt get you...wat I mean is that..."seekbar= progressbar + thumb"...I need that thumb here in my app, thats y Im gng for seekbar instead of progressbar..hope u got it

Comment: @adamp ...so u r saying that I should create a slider indicator Ui control of my own, instead of using the existing seekbar?..it must be tedious rite??..thats y I thought of using the existing seebar with some fine tuning on its behaviour :)

Comment: I'm saying that if you want a SeekBar where the user can't interactively change the current seek position, that's a ProgressBar. :)

Comment: @adamp Ohh okk okk...so is it easily possible to put a thumb for seekbar, as an indicator in my App?

Comment: You're not understanding the point here - you don't actually want what you think you want, because it's a bad idea. :) If you only want to show a non-interactive indicator, *you do not want to show a thumb.* Just use a ProgressBar, which will not have a thumb. Showing a thumb that the user cannot interact with is inconsistent and wrong on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you do this, but you can do the following:

```
public class MySeekBar extends SeekBar{

    private boolean myEnabled;

    public void setMyEnabled(boolean myEnabled) {
        this.myEnabled = myEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(!myEnabled) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
...
```

Then use setMyEnabled(false) to disable touch input

Comment: This won't stop a user with a keyboard/trackball/d-pad on their device from changing it.

Comment: @Evgeny Nacu thanks man :) ...but is there any way to do this without extending seekbar class??..

Comment: @Evgeny Nacu I need a slider indicator to be used in my App, it just have an indicator which moves under a scale and points to various values. For this I thought of using a seekbar with setEnabled(false), so that the users cant move the indicator

Comment: @Evgeny Nacu is it the right way to use the seekbar for this purpose, or should I create a custom control of my own?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my same problem with this :

```
 normalSB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        int originalProgress;

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {


            if (fromUser == true) {
                seekBar.setProgress(originalProgress);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            originalProgress = seekBar.getProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });
```

Hope it can help you :D